# Which is recommended to use in Typescript? A class type object or any type with many params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am new to Typescript and Javascript. I have written the following piece of code which works fine. I want to understand which is good and recommended to use in Typescript. Let me explain a bit. When we pass more than 4 parameters lets say 8 parameters, sonar complains. So we create an object and populate all the required fields and pass to a function and we get the result. We can also define all the fields inside curly braces like this given below.

```
const pType: any = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Abraham"};
```

At the same time, we can define a class like this.

```
export class Person {

private _firstName: string = "";
private _lastName: string = "";

// All get set methods/functions

}
```

Please help me to understand the difference between the above two, which is better and why in terms of memoray usage. I have written the sample class for simplicity.

```
export class PassNReturnMultipleParams {
    
    public getAddress_Type1(person: Person): Address {
        console.log("First Name: ", person.firstName);
        // write logic to validate
        const address: Address = new Address();
        address.cityName = "Bangalore";
        address.flatName = "#123";
        address.streetName = "Richmond Road";
        
        return address;
    }
    
    public getAddress_Type2(pType: any): any {
        console.log("First Name: ", pType.firstName);
        // write logic to validate
        const adrsType: any = {cityName: "Bangalore", flatName: "#123", streetName: "Richmond Road"};
        return adrsType;
    }
    
    public check_Type1() {
        const person: Person = new Person();
        person.firstName = "John";
        // Set other values
        const adrs: Address = this.getAddress_Type1(person);
        console.log("Address City Name: ", adrs.cityName);
    }
    
    public check_Type2() {
        const pType: any = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Abraham"};
        // Set other values
        const adrs: any = this.getAddress_Type2(pType);
        console.log("Address City Name: ", adrs.cityName);
    }
    
}

const test: PassNReturnMultipleParams = new PassNReturnMultipleParams();
test.check_Type1();
test.check_Type2();
```

In the above class, there are two functions `getAddress_Type1()` and `getAddress_Type2()`, which one is always recommended in Javascript, Typescript world. Both work fine for me.

Comment: Highly recommend reading through https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html and maybe some javascript basics, because you're basically asking for an entire explanation of the class system and typescript.

Comment: I am asking which one is recommended to use and which one should be memory efficient.

Comment: I like the one without any class structure ie const pType. What is it called `const pType: any = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Abraham"};`? It looks precise.

Comment: Never use a `class` until you actually need multiple instances, a constructor, and inheritance.

Comment: @Bergi, could you please provide some explanatory best practices, I will accept it as answer. I do agree with your comments and it looks good. This is the same concept in Python also to some extent. If I understand it correctly from your comments, we should use this approach `const someValue: any = {field1: "field value", filed2: "field value"}`. Am I right?

Comment: @PythonLearner No, I did not suggest to use `any`. You should declare your interfaces like in barinbritva's answer. You should not use `class` syntax for a `Person` pojo or for a stateless `PassNReturnMultipleParams` singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By my opinion, there shouldn't be usage of "any" in TypeScript. In this case I would recommend you use plain object with interface:

```
interface PersonType {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const pType: PersonType = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Abraham"
};
```

Comment: Hi Barinbritva, I like your answer, but is it always necessary to define an interface for some data holder as javascript provides an approach ? I am interested to know the widely accepted best practices for this.

Comment: Technically, you can use "any" of course. But the idea is "any" it's a type created for backward compatibility with JavaScript. If you really want to get profit from using TypeScript, I believe, you should specify types everywhere. Otherwise, it isn't clear what the actually sense of replacing JavaScript by TypeScript.

Comment: Speaking of memory usage (and performance), you should know, that defining an interface might look almost the same complex as defining a class in the source code, but in compiled version there is a big difference: all information about interface will be removed leading effectively to `any` type in runtime and smaller memory footprint, but class definition will bring some extra functionality to the compiled code and will take more memory of course, as well as some performance penalties

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty opinion-based but you need to take care of some programmatic principles.

Asking for memory efficiency between an javascript object and a class would result to a [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) and should be avoided.

You need to ask yourself what do you really need. In your case it will be 'something' that store data as a single instance that you can easily retrieve. If it's just about storing something that you will not frequently manipulate, then a simple `object` fulfilled all the requirements. Something else would be overengineerd.

Comment: I agree with you to some extent, it is simply storing some information, it may not be the case always. Just want to know what is the name of this structure `pType: any = {field1: "value1", field2": "value2"}`?

Comment: @PythonLearner This structure is called an [object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) in javascript.